# Does callback feature use select() call, internally?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, select, callback, asynccallback

In the below sample jquery code:

```
function getData() { 
   $.ajax({ 
             url : 'example.com', 
             type: 'GET', 
             success : handleData 
         }) 
}
```

---

Does `select()` system call on a socket that receives data, help invoke callback  `handleData()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. This might be `select`, `poll`, `kqueue`, `epoll` etc - which are kind of similar mechanisms but not the same and which differ in scalability and availability on a specific platform. What they all provide is to trigger some kind of event or state change when a sockets gets ready for read or write and this can then be associated with some action like some callback.